# What's the difference between declaring a module in TypeScript with quotes vs without?

Tags: typescript

I am a beginning at writing TypeScript definition files and would like to know the difference between the following two constructs:

```
declare module activedirectory
```

and

```
declare module "activedirectory"
```

For some reason the former allows me to utilize any classes within one of my Angular services without any sort of import declaration (ex. `import activedirectory = require('activedirectory')`.  Whenever I declare the latter in my code, it destroys references to my internal modules, for example:

```
module myModule.Services {
    'use strict';

    export class MyService implements myModule.Interfaces.IMyService {
    .....
```

Can no longer locate the "myModule.Interfaces" namespace.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The TypeScript team recognized the confusion, and that's why modules without quotes are now called namespaces.

> Going forward, internal modules will be called ‘namespace’.  We chose to use this term because of the closeness between how this form works and namespaces in other languages [...]
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-typescript-1-5.aspx

The quoted modules are ES6 modules, and need to be be imported using an import statement like `import 'activedirectory';`

Comment: Thank you very much mallison--I also appreciate the reference.

Comment: @mallison--can you provide any more details on exactly WHY importing this node.js module would break my reference to "myModule.Interfaces" namespace??  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @slashp Nope, sorry, but only adding the import shouldn't break references. What kind of error is it throwing?

Comment: Check out my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531405/why-does-importing-a-node-module-break-my-internal-typescript-namespaces-in-atom