# what's the proper way to implement this custom typescript module?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let's say I want to implement and use the following ts module.  It's just a basic validator that validates a first name:

```
export namespace Validators
{
    export class NameValidator
    {
        constructor()
        {
        }

        FirstNameIsValid(firstName: string)
        {
            return firstName.length < 20;
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the correct way for me to implement the module above?  Also, what would be the correct way for me to reference and use this module from my ng2 component?  The following import statement doesn't work:

```
import { Validators.NameValidator } from './modules/name-validator';
```

Comment: nope that doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/34864779/7176268 . The gist of it is with angular there isn't a need for namespaces since we use a module loader to import only needed modules.

Comment: @LLai - interesting point.  I took another look at an ng2 component that I created based off examples provided at angular.io and it doesn't have a namespace, so it looks like namespaces are not used in ng2.  thanks for the insight!

Comment: np! as a side note, if you were to have 2 files with exports of the same name, you can import them with aliases import {NameValidator as AliasName} from "./name-validator"; (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: thanks! as I was developing my component, I recognized the need for what, in the js world, would be called a "module."  I googled and found the concept of "typescript modules." however, in the context of an ng2 app, if I have a standalone ts class which does not map to an ng2 architecture type, should I refer to that as a supporting "module" or supporting "class" since the "class" keyword is used explicitly?

Comment: I view a "module" as a functional space that executes within its own scope. (for example a ts file that has exports has its own scope) A module can be composed of multiple variables, functions, and classes. So in this case it sounds like you are defining a "class"

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it in the past is to create a module

```
module Formatter{

  export class SsnFormatter {
        ssn: string;
        constructor(unformattedSsn: string) {
            this.ssn = unformattedSsn.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
        }
        formatSsn() {
            return this.ssn;    
        }
    }
}
```

Then within the other typescript files call it as

```
let f = new Formatter.SsnFormatter('111111111');
console.log(f);
```

As long as your class is within the same module namespace you should be able to reference it directly.

This was from an angular 1.x project but the version of TS or angular should not matter this is typescript communicating between modules.