# Getting "Can't resolve all parameters for" only when building demo app for production

Tags: angular

I have a custom library and a demo project both on angular 7. The library is building fine, the demo project as well and they're also running correctly. The problem happens when I try to build the demo site using the prod tag `ng build --prod`. Then I get the warning and error below:

> Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for DialogService in /Users/eestein/Documents/dev/sdk-front/node_modules/@proj/components/proj-components.d.ts: ([object Object], [object Object], ?, ?, [object Object], [object Object]). This will become an error in Angular v6.x
>
> Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for ɵa in /Users/eestein/Documents/dev/sdk-front/node_modules/@proj/components/proj-components.d.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x

The error:

> ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for ɵbw in /Users/eestein/Documents/dev/sdk-front/node_modules/@proj/components/proj-components.d.ts: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?, [object Object], [object Object]).

I tracked the warnings and errors down to the offending parts, they are:

### 1 - First warning:

```
...
constructor(
    private overlay: OverlayService,
    private injector: Injector,
    @Optional() @Inject(SdkConstants.Dialog.DefaultOptionsInjectionToken) private defaultOptions: DialogConfig,
    @Inject(SdkConstants.Dialog.ScrollStrategyInjectionToken) scrollStrategy: any,
    @Optional() @SkipSelf() private parentDialog: DialogService,
    private overlayContainer: OverlayContainerService
) {
    this.scrollStrategy = scrollStrategy;

    console.group('dialog');
    console.log('defaultOptions', defaultOptions);
    console.log('scrollStrategy', scrollStrategy);
    console.groupEnd();
}
...
```

The compiler is complaining it can't resolve defaultOptions and scrollStrategy, even though the first is marked as optional and the second is provided:

```
export function dialogScrollStrategyProviderFactory(overlay: OverlayService): () => BaseScrollStrategy {
    const result = () => overlay.scrollStrategies.block();
    return result;
}

...

providers: [
    DialogService,
    {
        provide: SdkConstants.Dialog.ScrollStrategyInjectionToken,
        deps: [OverlayService],
        useFactory: dialogScrollStrategyProviderFactory
    }
]
```

### 2 - Second warning (same as error):

```
constructor(
    private dialogService: DialogService,
    private overlayService: OverlayService,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    @Inject(SdkConstants.Datepicker.ScrollStrategyInjectionToken) scrollStrategy: any,
    @Optional() private dateService: DateService,
    @Optional() @Inject(DOCUMENT) document: any
) {
    this.document = document;
    this.scrollStrategy = scrollStrategy;

    console.group('datepicker');
    console.log('scrollStrategy', this.scrollStrategy);
    console.groupEnd();
}
```

The compiler is complaining it can't resolve scrollStrategy, even though it is provided.

Output from both console.logs:

[image]

As you can see, if I run the demo project and the referred components everything works just fine. It's only when I run `ng build --prod` on the demo project I get the build error.

For the past two weeks I have been reading a lot of issues on GitHub and SO questions about "Can't resolve all parameters for ..." and others, but not one seems to be directly related to my problem.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

PS: Please let me know if more bits of code would help to identify the problem better.

**Update (adding InjectionToken's definition):**

```
export namespace SdkConstants {
    export class Dialog {
        public static DefaultOptionsKey = 'dialog-default-options';

        public static DefaultOptionsInjectionToken =
            new InjectionToken<() => BaseScrollStrategy>(Dialog.DefaultOptionsKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check for `public` / `private` properties. Prod builds are picky with them...

Comment: @JSG_85 Thanks, but what do you mean exactly? Change the public to private or the opposite? Just check if private properties are being accessed at the template?

Comment: Yeah, I've had trouble before using private properties in the template. Usually there are compile-time warnings/errors, but depends on your build system I suppose. 
When I changed all the component's template-related properties to public, the errors went away.

Comment: @JSG_85 thanks, I know about those errors as well, they're not related to my problem, though.

Comment: "If we want to emit TypeScript as output of the AoT compilation process we must make sure we access only public fields in the templates of our components". from https://blog.mgechev.com/2016/08/14/ahead-of-time-compilation-angular-offline-precompilation/#the-context-property

Comment: @JSG_85 thanks, but again, as I said, it is not related to my problem. I have no private properties being accessed by templates.

Comment: Please post the definition of the InjectionTokens. I looks like you get the error only for the parameters that are injected using a token.

Comment: @AlesD that's partially true, I have other injection tokens throughout the app not giving the error, but I have updated the code with one example, please let me know if you need more bits of code. They all follow the same pattern, though. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior by mimicking your sample. Are this tokens and services part of the library and you do the registrations in the application?

Comment: @AlesD they're registered in their respective modules. In the first code sample, you can see one of them being registered. Also, do you have the same structure as I do? Because I get no errors by just building the library, it's only when I add it to the sample app and build it using the prod tag that I get the error. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Perhaps you are missing `@Injectable()` annotation for `DialogService`?

Comment: @penleychan thanks, but no. `@Injectable() export class DialogService`, it's not using `provideIn: 'root'`, because it is provided by its own module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your issue and the problem is that you use a namespace for the constants. Using namespaces is not recommended in Angular. Check also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852909/using-angular-2-with-typescript-and-namespaces).

Here is a sample how you can emulate the same structure using a class instead of a namespace this solves the build issue.

```
export class Dialog {
  public static DefaultOptionsKey = 'dialog-default-options';

  public static DefaultOptionsInjectionToken =
      new InjectionToken<ScrollStrategyProducer>(Dialog.DefaultOptionsKey);
}

export class SdkConstants {
  public static Dialog: typeof Dialog = Dialog;
}
```

Comment: that was it, thank you. I don't think I'd have ever gotten to that solution unless by stumbling upon it... I really like angular, but these error messages are usually the worst! Thanks again!