# Objects from file compiled with angular2 can't be found by other files during compilation

Tags: typescript, angular

**Background**

I'm converting a decent-sized project from Angular 1.3 to Angular 2. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 as my builder, including NPM for the package management. I'm not using Gulp, and have no plans to convert to it, because I'm updating this project piecemeal.

The original layout of the project was a top-level Typescript project, plus several child Typescript projects. As part of the update, I deleted all of the child project files, included everything under the top-level project, and used tsconfig files to break up the compilation into separate segments. (This part worked fine, and the website works just like it did before I put everything under the top-level project.)

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, a Nuget package of Typescript 1.8, and ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.2

**The Problem**

My problem is with using the UpgradeAdapter (on advice from [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html)). I started by adding this to the top of the bootstrapping file (angularengine.ts in my project):

```
import { UpgradeAdapter } from "@angular/upgrade";
```

When compiling, I immediately get errors – but *not* from the file I edited! Instead, any other file that references classes/interfaces from angularengine.ts can't find those classes. The errors are coming from the compiler, and they look like this:

```
CommonControls/1.1.0/js/controls/measurechartcontrol.ts(83,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AngularWatcherCallback'.
CommonControls/1.1.0/js/core/bootstrap.ts(45,71): error TS2339: Property 'AngularEngine' does not exist on type 'typeof Web'.
mc.common/1.0.0/js/common.ts(8,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AngularEngine'.
```

Note that there are zero errors about compiling angularengine.ts itself - it just can't be found elsewhere. I've tried running tsc.exe from the command line and gotten exactly the same results - no errors inside angularengine.ts, errors finding its classes.

(The class is Domain.Web.AngularEngine, the interface is Domain.Web.AngularWatcherCallback.)

Again: my main problem is that this **will not compile via tsc**. I'm aware that I still need to include the various scripts in the HTML.

**More Detailed Configuration**

Here's the tsconfig.json. (Typings/commoncontrols has a manually-created .d.ts file used by other projects; it's omitted to avoid duplicate identifiers. TypescriptModules is where those other projects live.)

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "TypescriptModules",
    "Typings/commoncontrols"
  ]
}
```

package.json (a clone of the [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), minus the tasks & dev-dependencies, which are handled by Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 plus a Nuget package of Typescript 1.8.):

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

Summary of angularengine.ts (It's creating a simplified interface to Angular watches):

```
import { UpgradeAdapter } from "@angular/upgrade"; // The mere *existence* of this line means the classes in this file cannot be found.
module Domain.Web {
    export class AngularEngine {
        private appName = "uifxApp";
        private controllerName = "uifxController";
        private app: any = null;
        constructor(otherModules: string[]) {
            this.app = angular.module(this.appName, otherModules);

            this.app.controller(this.controllerName, ["$scope", function ($scope: any) {
                $scope.$mcConfigs = $mcConfigs;
                $scope.$mcConfigs.$page = (<any>Domain.Web).Page;
            }]);
        }
        public Initialize(callback: Function) {
            var elem = document.body;
            elem.setAttribute("ng-controller", this.controllerName);

            $.when(angular.bootstrap(elem, [this.appName])).done($.proxy(function () {
                 // do more stuff
            });
        }
    }
    export interface AngularWatcherCallback {
        (newVal: string,
            oldVal?: string,
            path?: string[],
            expression?: string): void
    }
}
```

Summary of bootstrap.ts, which uses the AngularEngine class after the Domain and Domain.Web objects get created:

```
///<reference path="./angularengine.ts"/>     // It's in the same directory.
$(document).ready(function() {
    var callback = function() {
        var renderer = new Domain.Web.RenderEngine();
        renderer.renderAll();
    }

    Domain.Web.angularEngineInstance = new Domain.Web.AngularEngine();
    Domain.Web.angularEngineInstance.Initialize(callback);
});
```

**What I've tried**

1. Switching the module around in tsconfig.json. commonjs, umd, amd, and system all have the same problem. (es6 and es2015 both tell me that I can't compile with ES5 and expect to use ES6 modules, which I find perfectly reasonable.)
2. Actually using the UpgradeAdapter to bootstramp Angular. Adding more code doesn't help.
3. Fiddling with the `<reference>` nodes in other files. "./angularengine.ts", "angularengine.ts", removing the references, etc.
4. Reading some other answers about "cannot find module angular2/core", which I had earlier but is now working correctly since I fixed the tsconfig.

Is there something I'm missing about how imports work in TypeScript 1.8, that changes something significant about how other files are linked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does importing a node module break my internal Typescript namespaces in atom-typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531405/why-does-importing-a-node-module-break-my-internal-typescript-namespaces-in-atom)

Comment: Now that I've looked at the other question, I see that my problem is just another form of "adding import statements means that TypeScript treats your code as an external module, and namespaces become not only useless but a problem".