# Manually add TypeScript typings for npm utility

Tags: typescript

I'm setting up TypeScript in an existing JS project, and I'm trying to figure out how to add typings to an untyped npm module, since I know it'll come up.

This line

`import X from 'foo';`

errors out with `Cannot find module 'foo'`

In `typings/modules` I have a `foo` folder with an index.d.ts file therein with

```
declare module foo {
    export default class XXX{

    }
}
```

In the parent `typings/index.d.ts` I've added

`/// <reference path="modules/foo/index.d.ts" />`

But still nothing.

My tsconfig.json file looks like this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "es2015",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
        "typeRoots" : ["./typings/modules", "./node_modules/@types"]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "./src/**/*.tsx"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your module with quotes:

```
declare module "foo" {
    export default class XXX{

    }
}
```

Seems crazy? Modules declared without quotes are actually similar to namespaces. So you are not actually declaring a module in your code.

From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> “Internal modules” are now “namespaces”. “External modules” are now
>   simply “modules”, as to align with ECMAScript 2015’s terminology,
>   (namely that module X { is equivalent to the now-preferred namespace X
>   {).

Also see: [What's the difference between declaring a module in TypeScript with quotes vs without?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528902/whats-the-difference-between-declaring-a-module-in-typescript-with-quotes-vs-wi)

Comment: plus one thanks.  Will test as soon as I'm not afk and accept.