# Typescript full-qualify namespace vs import what is the difference

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces

Hi I have some problems understanding namespaces in Typescript...
What is the difference between this:

```
export class FileBrowser {
    ...
    attached() {
        let elem = $("#file-manager");
        elem.dxFileManager({
            name: "fileManager",
            fileProvider: new DevExpress.fileProvider.RemoteFileProvider({
            })           
        });
    }
}
```

and this:

```
import RemoteFileProvider from 'devextreme/ui/file_manager/file_provider/remote';

export class FileBrowser {
    ...
    attached() {
        let elem = $("#file-manager");
        elem.dxFileManager({
            name: "fileManager",
            fileProvider: new RemoteFileProvider({                
            })           
        });
    }
}
```

So in the first one (that compiles but does not work!) I specify `RemoteFileProvider` with fully qualified namespace name and without importing it. Where in the second one (that works) I use import and then reference `RemoteFileProvider` without fully-qualify it.

The firs code does compile without problems, but then at runtime throws:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'RemoteFileProvider' of undefined

While the second one works flawlessly.

**Update**
The declarations are:

```
declare module DevExpress {...}
declare module DevExpress.fileProvider {
    ...
    export class RemoteFileProvider extends FileProvider {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example assumes you have declared a global namespace like:

```
namespace DevExpress {
    export namespace fileProvider {
        export class RemoteFileProvider {
            constructor(someProp: {}) {}
        }
    }
}
```

This namespace is embedded in a script file (not a module with `import`/`export`), is available on the *global* JS scope and can be used directly (doesn't have to be `import`ed). You also could prepend `window` or `globalThis` to access `RemoteFileProvider`:

```
new window.DevExpress.fileProvider.RemoteFileProvider(/*your args*/)
// or
new globalThis.DevExpress.fileProvider.RemoteFileProvider(/*your args*/)
```

In the second example, `RemoteFileProvider` is the default `export` member of the module `remote` with the absolute path `'devextreme/ui/file_manager/file_provider/remote'`:

```
export default class RemoteFileProvider {
    constructor(someProp: {}) {}
}
```

> The firs code does compile without problems, but then at runtime throws [...] while the second one works flawlessly.

That sounds like your namespace definition has flaws (see above namespace as proper example) or you incorrectly assigned `RemoteFileProvider` to the global scope. This could also be a hint, that you have declared an ambient namespace `declare namespace DevExpress` (or similar), so there is no runtime equivalent code of the compiler declarations.

Comment: The source is not mine so no changes. I have updated the question with additional info (module declarations) if You could take a look. It seems that those are modules not namespaces. So that's why they don't work when used as namespaces. But then why VS code does not report this as a problem?

Comment: Oh, that is some older code. `declare module DevExpress` (note: *without* quotation marks!) in pre TS 1.5 was called an internal module and if I am not mistaken is the exact same as the `namespace` construct, which was introduced in TS1.5+ and used up to now. Quintessence of your example is: they are namespaces, but they are ambient (i.e. without implementation, marked by `declare` keyword). So if there is no implementation elsewhere, it is clear that you get a runtime error. Modules work, because there is probably an implementation in `'devextreme/ui/file_manager/file_provider/remote'`.

Comment: PS: if you want to read more about those internal modules : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528902/whats-the-difference-between-declaring-a-module-in-typescript-with-quotes-vs-wi) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13774)